# Constructor for Instant class in Java?

Tags: java, time, constructor, instance

I know that I can create an Instant object in this way:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

And I don't understand why I can't create an Instant object like this:

```
Instant instant1 = new Instant();
```

I can't find any informations about Instant constructors, and I know Instant is not an interface or abstract class. Why I can't create an Instant object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because the designers decided not to expose any constructor, and to promote factory methods instead. `Instant.now()` is much clearer than `new Instant()`. `Instant.ofEpochMilli(34567L)` is much clearer than `new Instant(34567L)`.

Comment: read this [Java Pattern class doesn't have a public constructor, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758740/java-pattern-class-doesnt-have-a-public-constructor-why)

Answer (score 3):

Because the constructor is **private**. Don't forget that there are open source implementations of Java, and you can simply look at their [implementations](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/time/Instant.java) for such questions:

```
/**
 * Constructs an instance of {@code Instant} using seconds from the epoch of
 * 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z and nanosecond fraction of second.
 *
 * @param epochSecond  the number of seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
 * @param nanos  the nanoseconds within the second, must be positive
 */
private Instant(long epochSecond, int nanos) {
    super();
    this.seconds = epochSecond;
    this.nanos = nanos;
}
```

Comment: @pkpnd The `java.time` implementation is open source; it wasn't built by Oracle, and most of Oracle's Java is identical to OpenJDK, which is open source.

Answer (score 2):

The `Instant` source code declares a `private` constructor taking 2 arguments, which prevents auto-generation of the no-arg constructor. This is by design: the authors of the `Instant` source code wanted to prevent users from using the constructor, because they wanted to force users to use `Instant.now()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Private constructor is used because:**

- Sometimes we want to use the **Singleton Design pattern**. To achieve this, we declare our class's constructor as private and we create the `now()` method to provide this functionality.
- **Singleton Design pattern** provides only one object for the entire system so that we don't end up creating multiple objects which optimize our code and garbage collection.
  *Hope I answered*