# DAL Design/Load methods with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, constructor, instance, data-access-layer

```
public MyClass(int someUniqueID)
{
    using(//Session logic)
    {
    var databaseVersionOfMyClass = session.CreateCriteria(/*criteria*/)
        .UniqueResult<MyClass>();

    //Load logic
    }
}
```

*The code sample above is my current direction, although I've reached a point where I need a bit of a sanity check.*

With NHibernate(I'm green in this area), is it common or best practice to instantiate an object from a database within the class constructor? The alternative I believe, would be to have a static method that returns the object from the database.

*I've also come across a relevent question regarding [constructors vs factory methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628950/constructors-vs-factory-methods/628959#628959), however I don't believe this implementation fits the factory methodology.*

To add an additional question onto the above, if instantiation within the constructor is the way to go, I've always used some sort of Load() method in the past. Either a specific private method that literally matches properties from the returned db object to the new class, or via a generic reflective method that assumes property names will match up. I'm curious if there is another way to "load" an object that I've missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not like this approach.
IMHO , it is better to implement some kind of repository which retrieves instances of persisted classes for you.
As an alternative, you could also follow the ActiveRecord approach, where you could have a static 'Load' method inside your class, and an instance method 'Save' for instance.  (Take a look at Castle ActiveRecord).

But, for me, I prefer the Repository approach.

Comment: I think the Repository patter with the Unit of Work pattern might be what I was needing to come across. I've spent a bit of time in the LINQ world and slowly settling back down into reality here ;) Thanks for the response Frederik.