# What's the Difference of Javascript Object "new" keyword

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

Can someone tell me what is difference between:

```
function Customer(name, age) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Age = age;
}

var cust1 = new Customer('Your Name', 20);
var name1 = cust1.Name;
var age1 = cust1.Age;
```

and:

```
function Customer() {
    return {
        Name: 'Your Name',
        Age: 20
    }
};

var cust2 = Customer();
var name2 = cust2.Name;
var age2 = cust2.Age;
```

It produces the same output, after all, but the mechanics are different and I am not sure why.

what's the purpose of "new" in the first one though i could just do this:

```
var cust1 = Customer('Your Name', 20);
var name1 = cust1.Name;
var age1 = cust1.Age;
```

Comment: Well, no. 1 is a constructor function while no. 2 returns an evaluated object literal. Try `Object.getPrototypeOf(...)` on both and you will find a difference. The question is interesting and deserves a good answer as both patterns can serve a different purpose.

Comment: sorry, i updated the my post.

Comment: This is not a duplicate - the question is about constructor vs. factory functions, not constructor vs. object literal, and the answers to the existing questions don't answer this.

Answer (score 3):

The first uses a **constructor**, the second a **factory function**.

Constructors are functions that you invoke with the `new` keyword. Doing so allocates a new object for you and make `this` a reference to this new object so you can easily mutate it. Constructors are basically syntax sugar that mimics other OOP languages construct to create new objects.

Factories are simple functions that return a plain object. You are in charge of allocating the new object yourself and returning it.

The result is exactly the same at the difference that you can't use `instanceof` with objects created via a factory function.

Both have pros and cons that get beyond the subject of this question: [Constructors vs Factory Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628950/constructors-vs-factory-methods).

Answer (score 0):

The output is equal (more less) but the code behaves in two different ways

In the first case the 'function' is used as a constructor for a new Js Object
Differently in the second case the 'function' just returns an object.

There isn't a real difference between the two methods but the first is more used and recommended

console.log() the two results in:
constructor: `Customer { Name: 'Your Name', Age: 20 }`
return obj: `{ Name: 'Your Name', Age: 20 }`

Comment: i think you mean Customer: { Name: 'Your Name', Age: 20}(with colon), isn't it?

Comment: They belongs to different prototypes, the first belongs to the 'Customer' prototype while the other object belongs to the generic '{}' prototype

Comment: @JedMonsanto it outputs the prototype and the object, no semicolons

Comment: sorry, i updated my comment, the point is the prototype, the first one belongs to Customer, in the other one is a generic. got it!

Comment: I think that the advantage of using the constructor is the fact that you can implement methods to the Customer prototype

Comment: can you please review it again my post. if your answer still applies on my updated one.