# How should the factory pattern be used with Slim Framework?

Tags: php, slim, static-methods, factory-pattern

There are different general types of recipes, and each general type has different methods.  The database queries the ID provided in the URL to determine the type and a different class is used.

One option is:

```
$c['recipeFactory'] = function ($c) {
    return new RecipeFactory($this->get('pdo'));
};

$app->put('/recipes/{id:[0-9]+}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    //Factory will query DB and create and return object
    $obj=$this->recipeFactory->create($args['id']);
    $obj->update($request->getParsedBody());
});
```

Seems like more often than not, a static method is used to implement a factory, so maybe I should do the following:

```
$app->put('/recipes/{id:[0-9]+}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $obj=RecipeFactory::create($args['id'], $this->get('pdo'));
    $rs=$obj->update($request->getParsedBody());
});
```

But then, I am not using the container, but the following will not work as `$args['id']` not defined.

```
$c['recipeFactory'] = function ($c) {
    return new RecipeFactory($args['id'], $c->get('pdo')); 
};
```

Should static methods be used for the factory method?

How should the factory pattern be implemented with Slim Framework?

Answer (score 0):

> How should the factory pattern be implemented with Slim Framework?

It depends, in the example you provided I would clearly go with your first solution.

Having an actual object and not a static factory methods has serveral benefits:

- the factory can be [mocked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2666006/4244993) inside tests
- it encapsulates the PDO-instance; the route must not know that the factory needs a PDO-instance
- it is consistent, the PDO-instance is created by the container and no static factory is used for it

> Should static methods be used for the factory method?

See [Constructors vs Factory Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628950/constructors-vs-factory-methods).

Comment: Thank you.  Your referenced other post seems to favor static methods.

Comment: @user1032531 as I said, it depends what is better, your question is really broad, so you cant say that static methods are always better.